# Generate SQL for Nested And/Or Expressions on Joined/Included Entities in Sequlize.js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I can't for the life of me figure out how to generate AND/OR SQL for different sets of fields using Sequelize.js. Given the following tables (see below), how do I generate the SQL below using sequelize.js?

```
SELECT * 
FROM  FactTable1
      JOIN DimTable1 ON FactTable1.FKey_DimTable1 = DimTable1.Id
      JOIN DimTable2 ON FactTable1.FKey_DimTable2 = DimTable2.Id
//Important Part! Each grouped (ie. in parenthesis) expression below referes to two different tables/aliases.
WHERE (DimTable1.Dim1 = 'Foo' AND FactTable1.Fact1 = 'Bar') OR
      (DimTable2.Dim2 = 'Baz' AND FactTable1.Fact2 = 'Bugz')
```

**FactTable1**

- Id
- Fact1
- Fact2
- FKey_DimTable1
- FKey_DimTable2

**DimTable1**

- Id
- Dim1

**DimTable2**

- Id
- Dim2

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize has a feature described as [Top Level Where Clauses](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#top-level-where-with-eagerly-loaded-models) that enables parent Where clauses to refer to properties of joined (included) entities. The query above is serviced with the JSON below.

```
db.FactTable1.findAll({
  where: {
    $or: [
      $and:[
        {
          '$dimtable1.Dim1$': 'Foo'
        },
        {
          Fact1: 'Bar'
        }
      ],
      $and:[
        {
          '$dimtable2.Dim2$': 'Baz'
        },
        {
          Fact2: 'Bugz'
        }
      ]
    ]
  }, 
  include: [
    { 
      model: DimTable1,
      required: true,
      as: 'dimtable1'
    },
    { 
      model: DimTable2,
      required: true,
      as: 'dimtable2'
    }
  ]
});
```